Как исключить зависимость для определенной ос?
Написал программу у которой есть функционал вызова диалога выбора файла через gtk3. Так же у этой программы есть режим только текстовый, без диалога выбора файла. Но так как я использую в этой программе импорт который дает функционал вызова окон, то в зависимостях этот пакет указан и, напрмер, для андроид эта программа уже не собирается(gtk3 нет в репозиоториях термукса), хотя в андроиде можно спокойно использовать исключительно текстовый вариант. А есть ли какой то механизм, позволяющий, например, указать компилятору, что при сборке в ос андроид(чрез термукс) не нужно требовать gtk3. Идеально если можно это сделать добавив что то в .mod файл

А как вы ожидаете это будет сделано? В другом UI вероятно другая инициализация, взаимодействие и работа с элементами .. У них же нет общего интерфейса, определяющего основные механизмы работы. Для таких дел нужно планировать ОСки, на которых будет использоваться проект, и использовать UI, которая есть на всех этих операционках.

Поставьте в файл, который использует gtk3, тег // go:build (!android)
Тогда этот файл будет проигнорирован при сборке под андроидом, go mod tidy не станет извлекать из него зависимости, и го не станет искать gtk3 при сборке под Андроид.

Если я правильно понял, то это нужно прописать в .mod файл моего проекта. И в результате весь файл будет проигнорирован? А если там другие, нужные зависимости?или нужно переместить код использующий gtk3 в отдельный пакет и в этом пакете сделать отдельный mod файл?
